# How to decode a python unicode list of dictionaries?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a form variable that returns a list of dictionaries that looks like this:

```
share_with = u'[{\"text\":\"leiaorgana@mycompany.org\"},{\"text\":\"yoda@mycompany.org\"},{\"text\":\"anakinskywalker@mycompany.org\"}]
```

I'm trying to use a list comprehension to get the list of email address but the backslashes are throwing it off.

```
share_with = [item for item['text'] in str(share_with)]
```

But the only error I get is:

```
global name 'item' is not defined
```

How do I loop thru that form variable so that I can get a list that looks like this:

```
share_with = ['leiaorgana@mycompany.org','yoda@mycompany.org','anakinskywalker@mycompany.org']
```

Comment: That's not (yet) a list of dictionaries. It looks like JSON text; if it's JSON, you should use a JSON decoder on it.

Comment: Does JSON allow the backslashes? If not then you may be able to use https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you have is something very similar to a `JSON` object.

So, you have to decode it to a valid mapping then read you emails:

```
>>> share_with = u'[{\"text\":\"leiaorgana@mycompany.org\"},{\"text\":\"yoda@mycompany.org\"},{\"text\":\"anakinskywalker@mycompany.org\"}]'
>>> 
>>> 
>>> import json
>>> json.loads(share_with)
[{'text': 'leiaorgana@mycompany.org'}, {'text': 'yoda@mycompany.org'}, {'text': 'anakinskywalker@mycompany.org'}]
>>> l = json.loads(share_with)
>>> 
>>> l
[{'text': 'leiaorgana@mycompany.org'}, {'text': 'yoda@mycompany.org'}, {'text': 'anakinskywalker@mycompany.org'}]
>>> 
>>> [item['text'] for item in l]
['leiaorgana@mycompany.org', 'yoda@mycompany.org', 'anakinskywalker@mycompany.org']
```